# Why not use % change in regression instead of log diff?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics

Given that **log difference = percent change** why not make the series stationary by just using percent change as the regresor.

a. It's not an approximation and we can interpret an coefficient as a percent change even with larger changes in the variable.

b. This would also be easier for applying the inverse transformation to get our expected value

Comment: In general - we don't do "difference in logs" for regressions. We just take the log of the target variable. Transforming the target variable using log before doing a linear regression allows us to interpret the coefficients as "when $x_i$ is higher by 1, $y$ is expected to be higher by some percent." Admittedly, you need to transform the coefficient in order to see that percent directly. If you want to skip that step where we transform the coefficient, you need a transformation on $y$ that lets us do that.

Comment: Some reasons: 1. log changes are additive percent changes are not. 2. Many variables are positive by definition so percent change must be greater than -100 $\%$. Then the percent change cannot have a standard distribution whose support goes to minus infinity.